# Creating entries from JSON feed - plugin?

Tags: entries, import, json

I'm wondering if this plugin already exists and I'm just not finding it on Github or via Google. Essentially looking for a CraftCMS version of the ExpressionEngine plugin called "Data Grab" - http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab

This plugin basically lets you define a feed and run automated imports to create entries. Hoping someone has done this in Craft or has some pointers to a preexisting plugin!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Import](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import/) plugin by Bob Olde Hampsink can import CSVs. JSON support is on the roadmap, but in the meantime, it’s easy enough to convert JSON to a CSV with a little bit of Javascript.

Just paste this into your browser’s JS console on any webpage:

```js
var data = [
    { title: "Entry Title", body: "Body content" },
    { title: "Entry Title 2", body: "More body content" },
    // etc.
];

function csvVal(val) {
    // Borrowed from http://phpjs.org/functions/addslashes/
    return '"' + ((val + '').replace(/[\\"']/g, '\\$&').replace(/\u0000/g, '\\0')) + '"';
}

var csv = '';

data.forEach(function(row) {
    csv += csvVal(row.title) + ',' + csvVal(row.body) + "\n";
});

console.log(csv);
```

Save the resulting CSV as somefile.csv and then you can upload it to the Import plugin.

Comment: Thanks Brandon! I need this import to happen regularly (based on a cronjob or something along those lines) and was hoping to avoid programming all of the JSON to field mapping, etc.

I ended up writing a small plugin that converts the JSON feed to RSS and then using the craft.feeds functionality to output them on the site.

Answer (score 6):

Check out the [FeedMe](https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe) plugin. It's pretty similar to DataGrab and Importer.

From the README:

> ## Feed Me
>
> Feed Me is a Craft plugin to make it easy to import entries and entry data from XML, RSS, ATOM or JSON feeds. Feeds can be setup as a task in Craft's Control Panel, or called on-demand for use in your twig templates.
>
> A common use-case for this plugin is to consume external feeds (news, events), but can also be used as a once-off task for importing content when migrating from other sites.
>
> [image]
>
> ### Features
>
> - Import data from XML, RSS, ATOM or JSON feeds.
> - Feeds are saved to allow easy re-processing on-demand, or to be used in a Cron job.
> - Map feed data to your entry fields. See Supported Fieldtypes.
> - Duplication handling - control what happens when feeds are processed again.
> - Uses Craft's Task service to process feeds in the background.
> - Database backups before each feed processing.
> - Troubleshoot feed processing issues with logs.
> - Grab feed data directly from your twig templates.
> - Craft 2.5 compatible.

*Disclosure: I authored this free plugin. Let me know if I can be of assistance!*

Comment: I expanded your post to include more details about your plugin (which looks great, by the way!)